# Android background camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I have searched on google/stackoverflow and tried many different solutions but none of them seem to work.

Okay here's what i wanna do:

I want to have a background service which displays a visible surfaceview with a camerapreview inside of it, like outside of the application i want to see myself (by using the front camera) in the surfaceview.

I know that is possible because i have seen other apps do that and i think it's really cool.

How would i do that?

Thank you for any help! THANKS ALOT :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a sample implementation](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/floating-camera) by an awesome googler Alex Lockwood